# Razor - access properties of foreign object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

**This question relates to an MVC4 project with Entity Framework (database first)**

I am passing an (EF) collection of 'Company' objects to a view.

I need to show the **name** of the 'Primary User' which is stored as int (foreign key) in each 'Company' object.

I am able to get the PrimaryUserID like this :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      <div>@item.PrimaryUserID</div>     
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to access the PrimaryUser object from the ID?

Is there a way to do this without passing a custom model containing the PrimaryUser object to my view?

Any help would be much appreciated!

//EDIT - this is how I currently pass the collection to my view

```
   public ActionResult Installers(int id = 0)
    {
        CompanyType installer = db.CompanyTypes.Single(ct => ct.Description == "Installer");

        return View(installer.Companies.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Navigation Property in your model.

Make sure your have included the property in your EF query.
( This is called "eager loading" )

```
public ActionResult Installers(int id = 0)
{
    CompanyType installer =
      db.CompanyTypes
        .Include( ct => ct.Companies.Select( c => c.PrimaryUser ) )
        .Single( ct => ct.Description == "Installer" );

    return View( installer.Companies.ToList() );
}
```

Then just access the property in your markup:

```
<div>@item.PrimaryUser.Name</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I'm not sure how to apply that to my example above, could you please give me a pointer?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Eager loading means that the data you specify in the `Include` will be loaded in one database hit.

Comment: any idea why I get 'ABC.Company' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'PrimaryUser'?  sorry to be a pain!

Comment: ok np. Have a look at your .edmx model and see what the navigation property is called on the Company table. EF might have set it to something other than `PrimaryUser`. You can edit the name in the properties window.

Comment: when I looked the navigation property was missing so I added a relationship in my database diagram and and renamed it to Primary_User (do I need to keep the scalar field PrimaryUser too?) and it's working! thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a navigational property set up to (what is your presumably) your users table in your EDMX? Ordinarily you'd just be able to do something like `<div>@item.PrimaryUser.Name</div>` if that was set up.